# Talend Exception NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-redshift, talend

I have a job in Talend where the main logic is

tMySQLInput ---> tRedshiftOutputBulk

The file is loaded in S3 but the data are not written in Redshift. I don't really get how this error is caused, because everything used to work fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: local_project/coredb2redshift_outbound_orderposition_0_1/CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition$1BytesLimit65535_tRedshiftOutputBulkExec_1_tRBE
at local_project.coredb2redshift_outbound_orderposition_0_1.CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.tMysqlInput_1Process(CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.java:1115)
at local_project.coredb2redshift_outbound_orderposition_0_1.CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.runJobInTOS(CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.java:1533)
at local_project.coredb2redshift_outbound_orderposition_0_1.CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.main(CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition.java:1370)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local_project.coredb2redshift_outbound_orderposition_0_1.CoreDB2Redshift_outbound_orderposition$1BytesLimit65535_tRedshiftOutputBulkExec_1_tRBE
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[statistics] disconnected
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share more details about what options you have selected in tRedshiftOutputBulk. have you tried using tRedshiftOutputBulkExec

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` means that the library might not be available in your environment, which would be strange.

Check with `Window / View` where you can select `Talend / Modules` if the module you need for this (I'd look for the name) is loaded and available. If not, you might need to add the component, but this might depend if you are using the Community or the Enterprise version.

Comment: The module is available.. I think it has to do something with Java itself, because i did an update and then it worked. However, now suddenly it raises the same error.